# How do I get <object classid>

Tags: jquery, mootools

Only accessible id right now is "dialog1". Given that information how do I traverse down to get the `<object classid>`?

I just realised that i've to do this with Mootools as the rest of the script is written in it. I'm completely new to Mootools thou'

$('#dialog1').children('NOLOCALIZATION').children('object').attr('classid'); seems to work for me. I'm actually using MooTools. How do I use this jQuery without conflicting?

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#dialog1" rel="vidbox" title="video">watch video</a>

</li>
</ul>

<div id="dialog1" class="window dialog" style="width: 806px; height:504px;">
    <NOLOCALIZATION>
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="806" height="504" id="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhi5x7V3WXE">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhi5x7V3WXE" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="FlashVars" value="width=806&height=504&dart_zone_url=&cms_id=AllBusiness&content_id=16009601&auto_start=1&auto_mute=1&playPreroll=0&playtremor=0"/>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="806" height="504" data="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhi5x7V3WXE">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhi5x7V3WXE" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="FlashVars" value="width=806&height=504&dart_zone_url=&auto_start=1&auto_mute=1&playPreroll=0&playtremor=0"/>
    </object>
    </object>
</NOLOCALIZATION>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for mootools:

```
document.getElements("a[rel=vidbox]").addEvents({
    click: function(e) {
        e.stop();

        var div = this.get("href").replace("#", "");
        var obj = $(div).getElement("object");

        // object may not be extended so normal getAttribute.
        var attr = obj.getAttribute("classid");
        alert(attr);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/XUyDU/

notice that in IE6-IE8, mootools does NOT extend the OBJECT element, hence obj will NOT have the otherwise available `.get()` or any other Element.proto that mootools adds.

Comment: I tried it. It didn't seem to work. Here the link http://move.clanteam.com/light-box5.html. I tracked in firebug. It didn't seem to grab the id. It says the val of id is null.

Comment: that's because you use version 1.11 of mootools and you did not specify. it had a different api. `.get("href")` should be rewritten as `.getProperty("href")` etc. Read the manual...

Comment: also, `e.stop();` should be `new Event(e).stop()`

Comment: @ Dimitar Christoff -- I'm trying to modify the code to make it work in mootools 1.1.2 as the rest of the script uses 1.1.2. I read the doc and using it as reference..but couldn't get it work. I appreciate your help

Comment: This works with mootools1.1.2 document.getElements("a[rel=vidbox]").addEvents({
    click: function(e) {
        
        var div = this.getProperty("href").replace("#", "");
        var obj = $(div).getElement("object");
        // object is not extended.
        var attr = obj.getProperty("classid");
        alert(attr);
    }
});

Answer (score 4):

```
var classid = $('#dialog1 object').first().attr('classid');
```

or i suppose:

```
$('#dialog1 object:not(object object)')
```

or

```
$('#dialog1 > nolocalization > object')
```

although I'm not sure how the browser handles a `<NOLOCALIZATION>` element.

After your comment about needing a dynamic version:

```
$(dialog).find('object').first().attr('classid');
```

Although really you just need to read through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) and be creative with your selectors. Test things out; see what works; see what doesn't.

Comment: thanks for helping. Actually I've an issue where I don't have direct access to id dialog1. When I click a link whose href value is set same as the div id's value, I'm extracting that value and storing it in a string. In that case how do I access the div?

Comment: $('#dialog1').children('NOLOCALIZATION').children('object').attr('classid'); seems to work for me